# python : If-else result Error occured, return value is not correct

Tags: python, pandas

I programed like belows:

================= python program =================

```
print(df.AMT.describe())
if (df.AMT.all() >= 100.000000): 
    df.BN_YN = 1
else:
    df.BN_YN = 0
df.groupby("BN_YN").size()
```

============= python program Result===============

```
count   850834.000000

mean       122.405618

std        607.791592

min          0.000000

25%         17.119406

50%         59.414306

75%        110.213483

max     215742.068175

Name: AMT, dtype:float64
```

---

```
BN_YN

0     850834

dtype: int64
```

As you can see, AMT has values over 100.000000
However, `BN_YN` has no 1.

How can I get the result both of 1 / 0?

Comment: The way you're presenting your code is too messy for anyone who want to help you. Since you're new to Stackoverflow, I suggest you to use `code sample` features of SO., by selecting the curly bracket from the toolbar (`{}`). Your code will be shown as in your editor/IDE

Comment: We have no idea what the output from `describe()` means.  If you want to know the value of `df.AMT.all()`, _then print that_.

Comment: `if (any(df.AMT>= 100.000000))`  is the correct syntax

Comment: df.AMT.all() : False

Comment: I changed code like this : 

if (any(df.AMT>= 100.000000)) 

However, the result is same ... -,.-;;;

Comment: the value of AMT : 617.173677   /    3881.615989  /   0.294949 ...... 

But the value of BN_YN is all '1'

Answer (score 0):

IIUC: using `numpy` [`where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) following would be the solution

```
df['BN_YN'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.where(x['AMT'] >= 100, 1, 0), axis=1)
```

can also be written like this:

```
df = df.assign(BN_YN=df.apply(lambda x: np.where(x['AMT'] >= 100, 1, 0), axis=1))
```

Comment: @TaijinKim If you have found this answer useful - please accept the answer by clicking the tick mark.